# Is there a way to put multiple values in a title of a plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

So I have a figure consisting in 3 plots, something like this:

```
figure
plot(yid);hold on
plot(yid_hat_pred);
plot(yid_hat_sim);
legend('y_{id}','y_{id}pred','y_{id}sim');
```

and 2 variables related to the last 2 plots: *MSEid_sim* and *MSEid_pred*.

Is there any way to put these 2 values in the title? Something like
**MSEid_sim=value, MSEid_pred=value** ? Or not necessarily in the title, but somewhere in the figure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
title(['MSEid_sim=' num2str(value) ', MSEid_pred=' num2str(value)])
```

This will create a char array.

Another nice thing you can do is using the DispalyName attribute of a plot, e.g.:

```
plot(yid,'DisplayName','y_{id}')
```

and in the end of your figure code just insert `legend show`